# Синхронизация Datagrid и EntityFramework

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework

Как сделать, чтоб при добавлении записи

```
USER user = new USER();
Context.USER.AddObject(user);
```

пустая запись добавлялась в DataGrid

Comment: `Datagrid.Refresh()`?

Если у вас, конечно, `Context.USER` — не `ObservableCollection`.

Comment: У Datagrid нет метода Refresh. Есть Datagrid.Items.Refresh, но он не помогает.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сделал как [здесь](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/vstudio/dd776540.aspx)
Пришлось сделать обертку для сущности USER из ObservableCollection. Вообще видео этой женщины не первый раз выручают. Довольно понятно даже с моим уровнем знания английского. Если сложно воспринимать VB, внизу есть исходники на C#.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте

```
CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(Datagrid.ItemsSource).Refresh();
```

Comment: Не прокатило.